# Suppress Android Gradle Plugin's warning when intentionally using Retrolambda?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, retrolambda

I am using the [Gradle Retrolambda Plugin](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda#gradle-retrolambda-plugin) in my Android library. The integration works well.

The Android Gradle Plugin, however, is annoying me. It announces that *it* can support Java 8 features, via de-sugaring. It suggests that I stop using Retrolambda:

> WARNING: One of the plugins you are using supports Java 8 language features. To try the support built into the Android plugin, remove the following from your build.gradle:
>       apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
>   To learn more, go to https://d.android.com/r/tools/java-8-support-message.html

**For technical reasons, I have decided *not* to follow this suggestion.** Retrolambda generates version 50 class files, while the AGP generates version 52 classfiles. The version 50 class files are compatible with a broader spread of consumers.

As per [Google issue 147311698](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147311698), I would like to permanently suppress this warning message, so that it doesn't clutter my build output. Is there some configuration / Groovy code I can use to target and suppress this specific message?

Comment: I would imagine this is showing because you are using JDK 1.8 - does the message go away if you change your compilation target to JDK 1.6?

Comment: @WoogieNoogie Ah, I didn't mention: I _am_ extensively using Java 8 features in source. So, setting source compatibility to a lower value isn't currently an option.

Comment: Retrolambda lacks support for third-party libraries that use Java 8 language features (even if it may work in compatibility mode). You might be riding a dead horse (when reading the author's comments on the Github issue tracker). See [migrate from Retrolambda](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support?utm_source=android-studio#migrate_from_retrolambda).